# Using QNetworkReply of a previous QNAM request as QHttpMultiPart body

Tags: c++, qt, http, post, qnetworkaccessmanager

In my application I need to post a large file which is available by HTTP location to another HTTP location without loading the whole file to memory.

I've already to tried to pass QNetworkReply received from the previous QNAM request instead of QFile, but no luck: the code compiles and starts downloading very_large_file.bin with no problems, but there does no POST request occurs:

```
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://mylocation/very_large_file.bin"));
QNetworkReply *reply = nm.post(request, &multipart);
QHttpMultiPart multipart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

QHttpPart filePart;
filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
  QVariant("application/octet-stream"));
filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader,
  QVariant("form-data; name=\"myfile\"; filename=\"test.bin\""));
filePart.setBodyDevice(reply); // working fine if I pass QFile instead of QNetworkReply


QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://myanotherlocation/post.php"));
QNetworkReply *reply = nm.post(request, &multipart);
```

By searching some info in Google I've found that the problem is that I'm trying to pass a sequential QIODevice while for some reasons QNAM is only working good with non-sequential QIODevice-s, so I need to implement a wrapper that converts QNetworkReply to something that QNAM would understand.

Does anybody can provide me with a minimal working example of that? It's necessary that very_large_file.bin will be transfered from mylocation to myanotherlocation chunk-by-chunk, rather from being fully loaded to memory.